# Python Difference Between Dates np array - current date

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

I am trying to find the number of days between a list of dates in a Pandas Dataframe and the current date.

I want to create a new column with the number of days between the due dates and the current date. For example:

```
+---------------------+------------+
|      Due Date       | Difference |
+---------------------+------------+
| 2019-04-15 00:00:00 |        146 |
| 2019-02-11 00:00:00 |         83 |
| 2019-03-11 00:00:00 |        111 |
| 2019-01-04 00:00:00 |         45 |
| 2019-05-13 00:00:00 |        174 |
+---------------------+------------+
```

I was trying to do:

```
current = np.datetime64('today')
df['Difference'] = df['Due Date'] - current
```

But I was getting wrong numbers. It works fine if I do them individually like:

```
df['Due Date'][0] - current
```

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: You could look into pandas [timedelta](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Timedelta.html) with `.days`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I was getting wrong numbers.

Works fine for me on Pandas 0.23 / NumPy 1.14.3, assuming `Due Date` is a `datetime` series:

```
print(df['Due Date'] - np.datetime64('today'))

0   146 days
1    83 days
2   111 days
3    45 days
4   174 days
Name: Due Date, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

More idiomatic would be to use Pandas-generated objects and `dt.days` if you want integers:

```
print((df['Due Date'] - pd.Timestamp('today')).dt.days)

0    145
1     82
2    110
3     44
4    173
Name: Due Date, dtype: int64
```

Note, for example, the one-day differential caused by working with the NumPy version. The real answer is *between* the two, but rounding up is probably not what one expects.

Comment: I guess it may not work in older versions. Can you post which version are you using ? If the OP puts his version maybe we can compare.

Comment: True , i'm sorry !

Comment: This worked for me: (df['Due Date'] - pd.Timestamp('today')).dt.days   Thanks @jpp :D

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to convert them to **datetime** to perform date-like operations.

```
df['Due Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Due Date'])
```

So the complete code would look like this:

```
df['Due Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Due Date'])
current = np.datetime64('today')
df['Difference'] = df['Due Date'] - current
```

**EDIT:**
Also another possible issue: i think you would need to add the current date as a column (or a Panda Series) so a good fix will be:

```
current = np.datetime64('today')
df['current'] = np.datetime64('today')
df['Difference'] = df['Due Date'] - df['current']
```

Comment: The current dtype of the column is set to datetime64[ns]

Comment: Still getting the same error: 2019-04-15 18000 days 23:59:59.999982

Answer (score 0):

I would check the format of `df["Due Date"]`. If it's not in the same date time format as todays date, then switch it. Broadcasting (the simple subtraction)should work if the formats match.

Otherwise, try using a lambda function to apply your changes:

`df['Difference'] = df['Due Date'].apply(lambda x: x - current, axis=1)`